# No disc writing tool is present Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, burner

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 but there is no disk writing tool like Brasero  disk burner present.

Comment: Haven't booted into 18.04 to make a screen shot and post a proper answer, but Brasero functionality is built into nautilus now (in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). Simply right click on the ISO file and choose option to burn to DVD or create Bootable USB.

Comment: Install it through the GUI or type `sudo apt-get install brasero` in a terminal.

Comment: Did you choose "minimal installation" instead of *normal installation* while installing?

Comment: NO I selected normal installation

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.) Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`brasero` is a package in the "universe" repository:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt policy brasero
brasero:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.12.1-1ubuntu3~16.04
  Version table:
     3.12.1-1ubuntu3~16.04 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     3.12.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

so, a simple `sudo apt install brasero` will install it.

Comment: apt policy should be of 18.04

Comment: …if you have the [*Universe* repository pocket enabled](/q/148638/175814).

Answer (score 0):

Brasero is a simple application to burn, copy and erase CD and DVD media: audio, video or data. It features among other things:

- On-the-fly burning
- Multisession support
- On-the-fly conversion of music playlists in all formats supported by
  GStreamer

To install open software center and search for Brasero or open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt install brasero
```

Afterward, type "brasero" in the search bar and you will find it. It's there in my OS.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes, of course. If it's not installed you will be redirected to the Software center. Just install it from there. I got it from ubuntu software center.

Comment: …if you have the [*Universe* repository pocket enabled](/q/148638/175814).